# Passing arguments from Perl to Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, perl, command, prompt

I'm trying to execute an .exe file in Windows Command Prompt from Perl.
I'm using something like

```
system($Execute_Program)
```

`$Execute_Program` looks like: `"Executable Program C:Path\foo1  --output_file c:\Path\foo2"`

The "--output_file foo2" format is required by the Windows executable file.
I get `"Error parsing options: Option 'output_file' does not exist"`, which I assume is coming from the Windows "shell-like" thing.

The command line sent from Perl to the Windows Command Prompt is constructed in Perl, not passed to Perl.
Perl itself is called with no
How do I get around this?
Thanks in advance.

Various versions of building a long string holding the entire Command Prompt and sending it via the System() command.

Comment: That's not what `$Execute_Program` contains. And the message is from the program you ran, not the shell.

Answer (score 1):

> "Error parsing options: Option 'output_file' does not exist"

Try `--output-file` (with hyphen, not underscore), maybe.

Otherwise you might look for [`GetOptions`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long#SYNOPSIS) function within the Perl code to see what options are there to pass to the executable instead.

Comment: Nice catch! We've all done this, but I didn't spot it.